# Is there a way to remove loaded module from probe function in linux device driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver

My requirement is to unload/remove the loaded module from it's own probe function.

> Is it possible? If yes then please help me in doing that.

For instance, I have kernel module called `ncr-power` and at boot time it gets loaded by system and `probe` function is called. I do not want to load it in certain situation but loading is not my hand so if I can remove after it gets loaded.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: I think of one way, if the probe() doesn't get called based on device tree property and this device tree node is a through a device tree overlay mechanism. Just a thought.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413204/how-can-a-kernel-module-unload-itself-without-generating-errors-in-kernel-log

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to load a module from the kernel, linux/kmod.h

```
int request_module(const char *module_name);
```

but there does not appear to be a corresponding call to remove a module. [LDD, chapter 11](https://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch11.html) describes request_module() and also user mode helper programs, which might be a mechanism to do what you want. If a driver invokes a call that removes the driver, what happens when that call returns?

I would do it this way:
 1. In your probe function, if you want the module unloaded, set a variable in driver.
 2. From a script or program that you run at startup, in user space, call an ioctl that returns the unload/don't-unload state.
 3. Unload the driver from user mode if indicated.